# Depending on a library with different version than the one available on servicemix (commons-pool 1.6)

Tags: osgi, apache-servicemix

I have a project (camel osgi bundle) on which I use commons-pool 1.6 (which supports generics) whereas servicemix has version 1.5.4

What do i need to do to have this dependency resolved ?

```
    Unable to resolve 219.13: missing requirement [219.13] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.pool)(version>=1.6.0)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `commons-pool` JAR is already an OSGi bundle, you should be able to install it with:

```
osgi:install -s mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6
```

Comment: oh thanks ! didn't know it was already an OSGI bundle (i should have tried though #duh)